# Why does my for loop only goes through once when i call function inside it?

Tags: node.js

I got list of videos from API, it has list of urls fo thumbnail and i would like to combine thumbnails of each video to gif. When i loop through videos and don't generate gifs it goes through 5 times as expected, but if i include function that should generate gifs it only goes through once, without any errors. I have no idea what is happening

I'm using node.js, discord.js, get pixels and gif-encoder modules to generate thumbnails.

```
  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    generateThumbnail(data[i].video.video_id,data[i].video.thumbs,function(){
      var tags = '';
      for(t=0;t<data[i].video.tags.length;t++){
        tags = tags + data[i].video.tags[t].tag_name+', ';
      }
      fields = [
        {name:data[i].video.title,
        value:value},
        {name:'Tags',
        value:tags}
      ]
      msg.channel.send({embed: {
        color: 3447003,
        thumbnail: {
        "url": ""
        },
        fields: fields,
      }});        
    });
  }   

function generateThumbnail(id,images,fn){
        var pics = [];
        console.log(id)
        var file = require('fs').createWriteStream(id+'.gif');
        var gif = new GifEncoder(images[0].width, images[0].height);
        gif.pipe(file);
        gif.setQuality(20);
        gif.setDelay(1000);
        gif.setRepeat(0)
        gif.writeHeader();
        for(i=0;i<images.length;i++){
          pics.push(images[i].src)
        }
        console.log(pics)
        addToGif(pics,gif);
        fn()

      }
var addToGif = function(images,gif, counter = 0) {
        getPixels(images[counter], function(err, pixels) {
          gif.addFrame(pixels.data);
          gif.read();
          if (counter === images.length - 1) {
            gif.finish();
          } else {
            addToGif(images,gif, ++counter);
          }
        })
      }
```

if i dont use GenerateThumbnail function it goes through 5 times as expected and everything works fine, but if i use it it goes through only once, and generated only 1 gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use var to declare for vars. Ie for(var i=0....
If you declare vars without var keyword, they are in the global scope. ..... and you are using another i var inside the function but now it is the same var from the outer for loop.